# Trying to start a script at startup

Tags: boot, script, init.d

I'm trying to write a script which starts a program with some parameters at startup (after boot) and therefore I'm using /etc/init.d.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          GetTempValues in /var/www/modules/programs
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Starts a program
# Description:       Starts a program

### END INIT INFO

#Actions
case "$1" in
    start)
        # START

        sudo chmod +x /var/www/modules/programs/GetTemperatureValues/startProgramm.sh
        sudo /var/www/modules/programs/GetTemperatureValues/startProgramm.sh 11 4 /var/www/modules/programs/GetTemperatureValues//logfile_11_4.txt

        ;;
    stop)
        # STOP
        echo "This does not do anything..."
        ;;
    restart)
        # RESTART
        sudo chmod +x /var/www/modules/programs/GetTemperatureValues/startProgramm.sh
        sudo /var/www/modules/programs/GetTemperatureValues/startProgramm.sh 11 4 /var/www/modules/programs/GetTemperatureValues//logfile_11_4.txt
        ;;
    esac

exit 0
```

But whenever I execute this command, so the script will be executed at bootup, I get a bunch of errors:

```
 sudo update-rc.d start_GetTempValues.sh defaults
```

I get these errors:

```
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K01bluetooth): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K06hwclock.sh): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K06networking): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K07umountfs): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K05rpcbind): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K05nfs-common): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K04umountnfs.sh): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K03rsyslog): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K02sendsigs): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K08umountroot): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K09halt): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc1.d/K01bluetooth): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc1.d/K05rpcbind): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc1.d/K05nfs-common): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc1.d/K03rsyslog): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K01bluetooth): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K06hwclock.sh): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K06networking): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K07umountfs): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K09reboot): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K05rpcbind): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K05nfs-common): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K04umountnfs.sh): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K03rsyslog): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K02sendsigs): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K08umountroot): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K01bluetooth): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K06hwclock.sh): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K06networking): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K07umountfs): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K05rpcbind): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K05nfs-common): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K04umountnfs.sh): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K03rsyslog): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K02sendsigs): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K08umountroot): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K09halt): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K07umountfs): No such file or directory
insserv: can not symlink(../init.d/umountfs, ../rc0.d/K04umountfs): File exists
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K04umountnfs.sh): No such file or directory
insserv: can not symlink(../init.d/umountnfs.sh, ../rc0.d/K03umountnfs.sh): File exists
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K08umountroot): No such file or directory
insserv: can not symlink(../init.d/umountroot, ../rc0.d/K05umountroot): File exists
insserv: can not remove(../rc0.d/K09halt): No such file or directory
insserv: can not symlink(../init.d/halt, ../rc0.d/K06halt): File exists
insserv: can not remove(../rc1.d/K01bluetooth): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc1.d/K05rpcbind): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc1.d/K05nfs-common): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc1.d/K03rsyslog): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K01bluetooth): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K06hwclock.sh): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K06networking): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K07umountfs): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K09reboot): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K05rpcbind): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K05nfs-common): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K04umountnfs.sh): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K03rsyslog): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K02sendsigs): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K08umountroot): No such file or directory
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K07umountfs): No such file or directory
insserv: can not symlink(../init.d/umountfs, ../rc6.d/K04umountfs): File exists
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K04umountnfs.sh): No such file or directory
insserv: can not symlink(../init.d/umountnfs.sh, ../rc6.d/K03umountnfs.sh): File exists
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K08umountroot): No such file or directory
insserv: can not symlink(../init.d/umountroot, ../rc6.d/K05umountroot): File exists
insserv: can not remove(../rc6.d/K09reboot): No such file or directory
insserv: can not symlink(../init.d/reboot, ../rc6.d/K06reboot): File exists
```

Please don't give me security advices, I'd be really thankful for working solutions.

Comment: sudo in an init.d script? not only is it not required, it may be the problem. Also, if you just want something to just run on boot (and not be a daemon) init.d is probably not the place to put it anyway ... and finally, if you're running jessie, then init.d is old school, learn/use the dreaded systemd

Comment: I recommend you to load/call your script from `/etc/rc.local`, init.d is a bit deprecated, use systemd instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ouch, you must take care of the rights
Setup executable permission on script,
take care the system runs as root best practice is to login as root, or

```
# su - (to transform in a real root)

# chown root:root /etc/init.d/mystartup.sh
# chmod +x /etc/init.d/mystartup.sh
```

Make sure this script get executed every time Debian Linux system comes up:

```
# update-rc.d mystartup.sh defaults 100
```

have fun

Comment: What does the 100 mean?

Comment: Its the two-digit sequence number that determines where in the sequence init will run the scripts.

Comment: two digits? Two hex digits, maybe? Because 100 is three digits... What am I missing?

Comment: Sure you are right the start sequence goes from S00 to S99 and the kill sequence from K00 to K99 .I was making fun . :P You could also specify the start or kill sequence as SS KK like this : `update-rc.d [-n] name defaults [NN | SS KK]`